# Extract number from string and replicate their associated value

Tags: r

I have this code currently:

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
args[1] <- "H2SO4"

components <- gsub('([[:upper:]])', ' \\1', args[1])
components <- c(unlist(strsplit(components, " ")))[-1]
```

which for the input of the H2SO4 results in a vector of:

```
[1] "H2" "S"  "O4"
```

Now how would I separate the digits from the letters and make the amount of letters of that type to the number extracted.
so the output would look like:

```
[1] "H" "H" "S" "O" "O" "O" "O"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can replicate the characters by the numeric part of the string with `gsubfn` and then extract the characters with `str_extract_all`.

```
library(gsubfn)
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(gsubfn('(\\D)(\\d+)', ~rep(x,y), str1),'[A-Z]')[[1]]
#[1] "H" "H" "S" "O" "O" "O" "O"

str_extract_all(gsubfn('(\\D)(\\d+)', ~rep(x,y), str2),'[A-Z]')[[1]]
#[1] "C" "C" "C" "C" "H" "H" "H" "H" "H" "H" "H" "H" "H" "H" "O"

str_extract_all(gsubfn('([A-Z][a-z]*)(\\d+)', ~rep(x,y), 
            str3), '[A-Z][a-z]*')[[1]]
#[1] "Fe" "Fe" "Fe"

str_extract_all(gsubfn('([A-Z][a-z]*)(\\d+)', ~rep(x,y), 
            str4), '[A-Z][a-z]*')[[1]]
#[1] "Fe" "Fe" "O"  "O"  "O"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "H2SO4"
str2 <- "C4H10O"
str3 <- 'Fe3'
str4 <- 'Fe2O3'
```

Comment: ow.. just found a problem... is I have a double digit it will only take the first one

Comment: @LoneCowCoder  Try changing `\\d` to `\\d+`.  I updated the code.

Comment: ugh.,... ty.. forgot about that expression

Comment: was testing something out and found that if I have something like Fe3 the gsubfn lists it as Fc(e, e, e) instead as c(Fe, Fe, Fe). I already modified the code so I can have the Fe without a number following.

Comment: @LoneCowCode Updated the post.  I haven't tested with all the cases, but it now works with the example you showed.

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly what the function [`inverse.rle`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rle.html) does, you just have to bring your input into the correct format:

```
repetitions = as.numeric(gsub('[[:upper:]]', '', components))
repetitions[is.na(repetitions)] = 1

rle = list(lengths = repetitions, values = gsub('[^[:upper:]]', '', components))
inverse.rle(rle)
```

Of course you can also reinvent the functionality of `inverse.rle` and it’s not hard, as the other answer shows. But it’s often a good idea to compose existing tools rather than reinventing them (to be clear: I don’t recommend my answer over akrun’s, which is more concise and direct, and potentially more efficient; however, it’s good to be aware of the tools that are at your disposal).

Answer (score 1):

Another try

```
args <- "H2SO10"

components <- gsub('([[:upper:]])', ' \\1', args)
components <- c(unlist(strsplit(components, " ")))[-1]

f <- function(x)
  if (length(y <- strsplit(x, '(?=\\D\\d+)', perl = TRUE)[[1]]) > 1)
    rep(y[1], as.numeric(y[2])) else x

f(components[1])
# [1] "H" "H"

unlist(Vectorize(f, USE.NAMES = FALSE)(components))
# [1] "H" "H" "S" "O" "O" "O" "O" "O" "O" "O" "O" "O" "O"
```

Comment: @KonradRudolph  Its not about your post :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dplyr way:

```
library(stringi)
library(tidyr)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

chemicals = data_frame(chemical = c("H2SO4", "C4H10O"))

elements = 
  chemicals %>%
  mutate(element_number = 
           chemical %>%
           stri_replace_all_regex("([A-Z])", 
                                  " $1") %>%
           stri_split_fixed(" ") ) %>%
  unnest(element_number) %>%
  filter(element_number != "") %>%
  mutate(element = 
           element_number %>%
           stri_replace_all_regex("[0-9]", ""),
         number = 
           element_number %>%
           stri_replace_all_regex("[^0-9]", "") %>%
           as.numeric %>%
           mapvalues(NA, 1)) %>%
  select(-element_number)

long_elements = 
  elements %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(result = 
           element %>%
           rep(number) %>%
           list) %>%
  unnest(result)
```